# Why is it not possible to "overwrite" a FormGroup in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hi I wanted to create a Create and Update Form for a object.

To differ what type of website should be displayed I give the component either a "/new" or a "/{imei}" with the navigation property.

--> /new --> create

--> /{imei} --> update

This will be implemented with the following code:

```
if (params.id === 'new') {
        this.addNotUpdate = true;
        this.generateCreateForm();

      } else {
        this.subscription.add(this.phoneService.GetPhoneByIMEI(params.id).subscribe(phone => {
          this.addNotUpdate = false;
          this.phone = phone;
          this.generateUpdateForm();
        }));
      }
```

```
generateCreateForm(){
    this.phoneForm = new FormGroup({
      imei: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, ValidationService.imeiValidator]),
      inputDevice: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelDevice: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      inputBrand: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelBrand: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      inputModel: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelModel: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      inputColour: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelColour: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      inputStorage: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelStorage: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      purchasePrice: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, ValidationService.priceValidator]),
      purchaseDate: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      saleDate: new FormControl(""),
      rentalStart: new FormControl(""),
      rentalFinish: new FormControl("")
    });
  }
```

```
generateUpdateForm(){
    this.phoneForm = new FormGroup({
      imei: new FormControl(this.phone.imei),
      inputDevice: new FormControl(),
      labelDevice: new FormControl(this.phone.device.kindOfDevice),
      inputBrand: new FormControl(),
      labelBrand: new FormControl(this.phone.brand.name),
      inputModel: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelModel: new FormControl(this.phone.model.modelName),
      inputColour: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelColour: new FormControl(this.phone.colour.colourName),
      inputStorage: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
      labelStorage: new FormControl(this.phone.storage.amount),
      purchasePrice: new FormControl(this.phone.purchasePrice),
      purchaseDate: new FormControl(this.phone.purchaseDate),
      saleDate: new FormControl(this.phone.saleDate),
      rentalStart: new FormControl(this.phone.rentalStart),
      rentalFinish: new FormControl(this.phone.rentalFinish)
    });
  }
```

So the create part of the component is ok, nothing goes wrong here, but when i want to call the same website with the update this error comes up:

[image]

I dont understand why this comes up, I initialize the formgroup instance, how can I fix this ?

First few lines of html code where the FormGroup is initialized:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="border border-light p-5" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
```

Comment: simple add a *ngIf: `<form *ngIf="phoneForm" ......>` this avoid initials errors until the form is not create -and at very first state when you want update the form is null-

Comment: Most likely the cause is due to your update is async since you need to grab the data. Ideal way to do this is that you should keep that form as a dumb component and you would just pass in the data via `@Input()` from your smart component. If input is undefined/null it's a new form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of code is asynchronous:

```
 this.subscription.add(this.phoneService.GetPhoneByIMEI(params.id).subscribe(phone => {
      this.addNotUpdate = false;
      this.phone = phone;
      this.generateUpdateForm();
    }));
```

so the code of constructor end with an undefined phoneForm.

Initialize your phoneForm, with a default form group, or use a *ngIf to check if phoneForm is not null/undefined.

Comment: thank you!
was a dumb error but I had no clue how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

simple add a *ngIf:  this avoid initials errors until the form is not create -and at very first state when you want update the form is null

BTW, not use two functions to make the same, just a simple function like

```
//make an interface
export interface IPhone {
    imei: string;
    inputDevice: string;
    ...
}
//make a unique function that return a formGroup
generateForm(data:any):FormGroup{
    data=data || {} as Iphone
    return new FormGroup({
      imei: new FormControl(data.imei),
      inputDevice: new FormControl(data.inputDevice),
      labelDevice: new FormControl(data.device.kindOfDevice),
      ....
    });
  }

//this make you simple use
if (params.id === 'new') {
    this.addNotUpdate = true;
    this.phoneForm=this.generateForm(null);
} else {
 this.subscription.add(this.phoneService.GetPhoneByIMEI(params.id).subscribe(phone => {
    this.addNotUpdate = false;
    this.phoneForm=this.generateForm(phone);
 }));
}
```

Comment: The only minor thing to note about combining the two functions into a single `generateForm` is that the form wasn't 100% the same as the validations are different on create vs update.

Comment: thank you that was a useful answer but @Dean is right, I need to implement two functions because I have different validations

Comment: sorry, I didn't  taken account about this